# let sublimetext run last used build command

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

As an example, there are two files, `main.py` and `module.py`, I could only run the project  when `main.py` is in the current active tab window by `Ctrl + B`. However, a big amount of my code work is in `module.py`, after some modification of `module.py`, I have to switch to `main.py` to run and test my code, frequently switching to `main.py` is not convenient, I wonder if there is a way to run `module.py` when the current file in the active tab window is `module.py` rather than `main.py`.

Briefly, I have  `main.py` and `module.py` opened in Sublime, after running `main.py` I switch to `module.py`, how to run `main.py` when  the current file in the active tab window is `module.py` rather than `main.py`?

I found a solution in [this post](https://irwinkwan.com/2013/08/22/sublime-text-always-run-a-single-file-in-a-project-no-matter-what-is-focused/) , but that requires to configure manually, I expect there is a feature to remember last build command so that I can repeat last command by some shortcut. It would be welcome if someone can guide me to write some plugin to implement the feature.

Answer (score 1):

The solution in the article you linked to (creating a custom build system that always runs `main.py` regardless of which file is focused) is the recommended solution. There is no built-in way to rerun the last build using the same file.

Sure, you could go through the time and effort to write a plugin, but why? The solution is right in front of you, and only requires you to put a couple of lines of JSON in your `.sublime-project` file.

Comment: I am not inclined to write `sublime-project files` manually per project, I expect there is a feature to remember last build command so that I can repeat running the command by some shortcut.
After running my Python  script, I saw the running command was logged in the console of sublimetext ![image|690x139](https://forum.sublimetext.com/uploads/default/original/3X/8/4/843cd04cd5b2c43a57fcb59dc02b2e36c1f40764.png) , I just need to get the latest running command and then run it by my plugin if triggered, but I cannot find a way to get the command , any help ?

Comment: @iMath you can "expect there is a feature" all you want, but it simply doesn't exist. All you have to do is select **`Project → Edit Project`** and put your build system there. If you're not "inclined" to do that, then you'll have to switch to `main.py` and run Build from there every time. The console output in your image is not accessible via the API, so even a custom plugin based on that won't work. Sublime is built on the concept of text-based configuration, and I honestly don't see what the problem is with editing one of those config files to get exactly the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Please keep in mind that Sublime is a tricked-out coding editor, not a full-featured IDE. Yes, it does have some features that are also present in IDEs, and plugins can expand on those features, such as the [LSP project](https://lsp.sublimetext.io/) and the [`Anaconda`](https://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/) plugin (not related to the Anaconda Python distribution), but even they don't provide every single feature an IDE does.